# Pc will not boot - power over HDMI?

Tags: boot, graphics-card, power-supply, hdmi

So i encountered the strangest issue with my PC today. I was using it last night, i shut it down as normal, then this morning, nothing, checked power leads, tried to remove power hold in power for 30 secs and try again, still nothing. And when i say nothing: the blue power light didn't come on, no fan or hard disk action, BIOS didn't output anything.

So i pulled the PC out, and took off the side, the system fan was still running, CPU was dead. Curious i pulled out the main power supply, and it kept spinning. At this stage i took a video of the rest of the process as i didn't think what i was seeing was possible.

Started removing every other cable one by one to see, in the end i was left with only Display Port and HDMI plugged in. Unplugged HDMI and everything shut down again. Then to get my PC to boot i had to remove my graphics card to get everything into a normal state then restart with graphics back in and its running again now 100%.

So the crux of my question is, what the heck happened? I don't want this to be a thing that keeps happening over and over again. Should i be concerned i have some faulty hardware?

If anyone can shed any light on what caused this i would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [HDMI 1.3a spec](http://www.microprocessor.org/HDMISpecification13a.pdf) there is a power pin that provides 5V/50mA, but it specifies that the power flows from the PC to the display.

However, MHL is a standard for connecting smartphones and mobile-tablets to displays, and while I couldn't find the spec, according to the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_High-Definition_Link) it allows power to flow from the display to the device, the reverse of HDMI, and to provide enough power to charge a smartphone.

I would look up the specs for your monitor/display online, if it supports MHL maybe it got confused. If it doesn't then it might be defective.

As for the PC, I would do stability tests like one would do when overclocking, such as Prime95 and memtest86. If both of those pass, and you don't encounter other problems with your PC, I wouldn't worry about it too much.

If you encounter this again I would suggest trying a different monitor for at least a few weeks before looking at any parts inside the PC.